# Problem with Costmap2DROS in Hydro

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently moved my code from Fuerte to Hydro and now have some issues with the costmap_2d, which I use as a local map in my obstacle avoidance module. Occasionally cells that should have higher costs due to the inflation step seem to have zero costs. When moving to Hydro I had to remove the call to Costmap2DROS::getCostmapCopy as it is not present anymore. Is it safe to just use the Costmap2D-Pointer returned by the new method Costmap2DROS::getCostmap()? Or do I have to Pause the Costmap2DROS before using the underlying Costmap2D?

For some reason the issue disappears when I set the Output-Level of the Costmap2D to DEBUG during runtime. So it really might be some timing issue between updating and querying the Costmap2D.

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133836/problem-with-costmap2dros-in-hydro/) by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1658 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution to this. It seems to be necessary to lock the costmap before accessing its data by something like:

```
boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(*(myCostmap2DROS->getCostmap()->getLock()));
```

Edit:
Ok, to actually use the costmap, for example in a function. you would do it like this:

```
void myFunc()
{
    Costmap2D* pCostmap = myCostmap2DROS->getCostmap();
    boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(*(pCostmap->getLock()));

    // Now you can use the costmap.
    [...]
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-03-05**:
I think I might be having a problem similar to yours. Do you think you could elaborate on the solution a little, please? For instance, how are you storing the pointer returned by getCostmap(), and do you have to do anything to unlock the 2DROS map afterwards? Still a newbie. Thanks!

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-03-05**:
You don't need to permanently store the Costmap2D-Pointer, as you can just get from your Costmap2DROS whenever you need it. The costmap will be unlocked again, once the created boost::unique_lock goes out of scope, that is in the example above when myFunc() returns.

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-03-13**:
That is very helpful, thanks!